# default "css-" class names using MUI styled-components

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, styled-components, emotion, css-in-js

I'm using Mui's styled components, and i've noticed it injects a class that starts with "css-"
and replaces the class name i've given to it in the code

I've tried to follow everything that was suggested [here](https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/interoperability/#css-injection-order) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71197017/can-we-disable-some-css-class-names-that-mui-is-injecting-onto-its-component) but without success (including StyledEngineProvider and CacheProvider with preprend true.

Here is the code and the result i'm getting:

Page.tsx:

```
import * as S from "./Page.style";
export default function Page(): ReactElement {
  return (
      <S.Container>
      </S.Container>
  );
}
```

Page.style:

```
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";
export const Container = styled("div")({
  paddingTop: "10%",
  paddingRight: "11%"
});
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9fea.png)

Expected result is the name is something like that includes the word "Container"

Answer (score 3):

There are two *steps* of this, what you want to achieve.

### 1. provide the styled options

```
export const Container = styled("div", {
  name: 'Container',
  slot: 'Root'
})({
  paddingTop: "10%",
  paddingRight: "11%"
});
```

This will add `css-[id]-Container-root` class to your component, but the problem is that you would likely also like to have just a clean `Component-root` class name on it, right? FFWD to second step.

### 2. generate class names and use them

MUI has two utility functions that they use with all of their components: `generateUtilityClass` and `generateUtilityClasses`. Both take the name of your component and an array of *slots* that you may use in your component. *Root* is usually the top of your component, but within you may have whatever components/containers or in other words *slots*, where you can apply these classes. These slots are of course a more complex thing not just CSS classes, but for this purpose, let's do that to your component:

```
const name = 'Container';
export const containerClasses = generateUtilityClasses(name, ['root', 'actions',...]);
export const Container = styled("div", {
  name,
  slot: 'Root'
})({
  paddingTop: "10%",
  paddingRight: "11%"
});

// ....

// and then within your component
return (
    <Component className={componentClasses.root}>
        ...
        <Stack className={componentClasses.actions}>
            <Button.../>
            <Button.../>
            <Button.../>
        </Stack>
    </Component>
);
```

`generateUtilityClasses` internally uses `generateUtilityClass` which interpolates CSS class names by doing the `` `${componentName}-${slot}` `` mainly. Except for the globally recognised states, it returns names `Mui-active`, `Mui-selected` and similar. To know which CSS class names will not be bound to your component, this is the list of global state names

```
export declare type GlobalStateSlot = 'active' | 'checked' | 'completed' | 'disabled' | 'error' | 'expanded' | 'focused' | 'focusVisible' | 'required' | 'selected';
```